# How do I add code to my form tag with javascript using this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the gravity forms wordpress plugin, and I want to add oninput to my form tag...
I am following the instructions on this page:
https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_form_tag/

However, the example they provide are for replacing something in the form tag, instead of ADDING something to the form tag.... How should the following code be edited to add an oninput event to the tag instead of replacing something inside of the tag? I don't know what to use instead of pregreplace...

```
add_filter( 'gform_form_tag', 'form_tag', 10, 2 );
function form_tag( $form_tag, $form ) {
    if ( $form['id'] != 3 ) {
        //not the form whose tag you want to change, return the unchanged tag
        return $form_tag;
    }
    $form_tag = preg_replace( "|action='(.*?)'|", "action='custom_handler.php'", $form_tag );
    return $form_tag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have a classic case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)  here.  You're asking how to change the tag to include an `oninput` attribute, but really you are trying to accomplish something else.

So, first I will answer your question directly:

```
add_filter( 'gform_form_tag', 'form_tag', 10, 2 );
function form_tag( $form_tag, $form ) {
    if ( $form['id'] != 3 ) {
        //not the form whose tag you want to change, return the unchanged tag
        return $form_tag;
    }
    // We know the form has the 'form ' in it, so replace that with 'form' plus the oninput you want
    $form_tag = str_ireplace( "<form ", "<form oninput='myFunction() ", $form_tag );
    return $form_tag;
}
```

But really, there's probably a better / simpler way.

Write some javascript - since you clearly are going to *use* javascript - that connects with the form:

```
// Since WordPress loads jQuery in no-conflict mode, this is the preferred "document ready"
jQuery(function($) {
    // "gform_3" represents the form you want to target.
    $('#gform_3 input, #gform_3 textarea').on('change', function() {
        // Do your "oninput" work here
    }
});
```

Simply change the ID to match the ID of the form you want to target - if your form is ID 23, then make it `#gform_23`, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. Really appreciate it. Your first solution works perfect, however, I'm unsure about the last one... how exactly to start with my oninput code.... will I litterally just replace "// Do your 'oninput' work here" with the code that are meant to be inside the double quotes of the oninput attribute? so should I just add for example: "amount.value=rangeInput.value;" or do I have to start that line with something else?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Cale's simpler answer; however, in some cases you still might want to put the event attribute (any event attribute) on the <form> itself. Here's a plugin that makes it really simple.

http://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-tag-editor/

Example usage:

```
new GW_Tag_Editor( array(
    'tag'          => 'form',
    'form_id'      => 123,
    'oninput'      => 'myFunction()'
) );
```